# how to create a filterable list with javascript based on 3 select boxes

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I need to method to implement something similar to what is on this webpage

http://www.brownthomas.com/brands/

I will have a list of brands on the page. each brand should have 3 pieces of information:

1. starting letter
2. store (could be mulitple)
3. category (could be mulitple)

So I need 3 select boxes, when one of the select boxes is selected it will filter the brands underneath based on this.

I would like the filter to happen within the browser through javascript.

So I was thinking, I some how add some extra information on the brands, and then remove everything from view that does not match the select box criteria.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Also I will be using wordpress and Advanced Custom Fields to achieve this from the backend in terms of entering the brands. I just dont know where to start.

i was thinking something like this

```
<div classs="brand-holder">
    <div class="brand-column">
        <h3>0-9</h3>
        <ul class="brand-list">
            <li data-alpha="0" data-store="Arnotts,BrownThomas" data-category="Mens Wear, Shoes">Brand name</li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="brand-column">
        <h3>A</h3>
        <ul class="brand-list">
            <li data-alpha="A" data-alpha="A" data-store="Arnotts,Dundrum" data-category="Womens Wear, Cosmetics" >A Brand Name</li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

But I don't know how, I would build this in the backend.

==========edit added=========
 i want to the backend doesn't allow me segregate the categories relevant to the stores . here is an example Chanel, Brown Thomas Sells women's wear, footwear,jewellery and accessories and beauty. Arnotts only sells beauty. Dundrum sells beauty and accessories. how would i achieve this?

i was thinking something like this would work for layout , but i wouldnt know the javascript to work with the select boxes

```
<div classs="brand-holder">

<div class="brand-column">
    <h3>A</h3>
    <ul class="brand-list">
        <li data-alpha="A" data-store="Arnotts,Dundrum,brownThomas" data-arnotts-category="Womens Wear, Cosmetics" data-dundrum-category="Womens Wear" data-brownThomas-category="Beauty" >A Brand Name <i>[store:Arnotts,Dundrum :: category: Womens Wear, Cosmetics]</i></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

-== edit added======

This is how the information is selected in the backend at the moment,

[image]

but i need it so it will work with something like this

[image]

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Some time ago i've created a jquery plugin to achive this automatically https://github.com/Carz-il/Any-List-Smart-Filter (there is a demo to see if it meets your requirments..)

Comment: and yes i can use jquery

Comment: It looks like the site example you gave uses a database backend with a php or asp front end to alter the results building each drop-down box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code... **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C34Lw/1/)**

**HTML**

No change in your data part, just added the `select` elements.

```
<select id="alpha" onchange="selectData();">
    <option value="">Choose A-Z</option>
    <option value="0">0-9</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select id="store" onchange="selectData();">
    <option value="">Any Store</option>
    <option value="Arnotts">Arnotts</option>
    <option value="BrownThomas">BrownThomas</option>
    <option value="Dundrum">Dundrum</option>
</select>
<select id="category" onchange="selectData();">
    <option value="">Any Category</option>
    <option value="Mens Wear">Mens Wear</option>
    <option value="Shoes">Shoes</option>
    <option value="Womens Wear">Womens Wear</option>
    <option value="Cosmetics">Cosmetics</option>
</select>

<div classs="brand-holder">
    <div class="brand-column">
        <h3>0-9</h3>
        <ul class="brand-list">
            <li data-alpha="0" data-store="Arnotts,BrownThomas" data-category="Mens Wear, Shoes">Brand name <i>[store:Arnotts,BrownThomas :: category: Mens Wear, Shoes]</i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="brand-column">
        <h3>A</h3>
        <ul class="brand-list">
            <li data-alpha="A" data-store="Arnotts,Dundrum" data-category="Womens Wear, Cosmetics" >A Brand Name <i>[store:Arnotts,Dundrum :: category: Womens Wear, Cosmetics]</i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function selectData() {
    var alpha = document.getElementById('alpha').value;
    var store = document.getElementById('store').value;
    var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
    var i;
    var j;
    var flag;

    items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    // Hide/show items
    for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        a = items[i].getAttribute('data-alpha');
        s = items[i].getAttribute('data-store').split(",");
        c = items[i].getAttribute('data-category').split(",");

        // To be safe
        for(j = 0; j < s.length; j++) s[j] = s[j].trim();
        for(j = 0; j < c.length; j++) c[j] = c[j].trim();

        if((alpha == "" || a == alpha) && (store == "" || s.indexOf(store) != -1) && (category == "" | c.indexOf(category) != -1)) {
            items[i].classList.remove("hidden");
        } else {
            items[i].classList.add("hidden");
        }
    }

    // Clear empty groups
    groups = document.getElementsByClassName("brand-list");

    for(i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        flag = true;

        for(j = 0; j < groups[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
            node = groups[i].childNodes[j];

            if(node.nodeName.trim() == "LI" && (node.className == "" || node.className.indexOf('hidden') == -1)) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Remove the whole div
        if (flag) {
            groups[i].parentNode.classList.add("hidden");
        } else {
            groups[i].parentNode.classList.remove("hidden");
        }
    }
}
```

**jQuery *(instead of Javascript)***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function selectData() {
        var alpha = $("#alpha").val();
        var store = $("#store").val();
        var category = $("#category").val();
        var j;

        // Hide items
        $("li").each(function() {
            a = $(this).attr('data-alpha');
            s = $(this).attr('data-store').split(",");
            c = $(this).attr('data-category').split(",");

            // To be safe
            for(j = 0; j < s.length; j++) s[j] = s[j].trim();
            for(j = 0; j < c.length; j++) c[j] = c[j].trim();

            if((alpha == "" || a == alpha) && (store == "" || s.indexOf(store) != -1) && (category == "" | c.indexOf(category) != -1)) {
                $(this).removeClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }
        });

        // Hide empty sections
        $(".brand-list").each(function() {
            if($(this).children("li").not(".hidden").length > 0) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("hidden");
            } else {
                $(this).parent().addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
    }

    $("#alpha").on("change", selectData);
    $("#store").on("change", selectData);
    $("#category").on("change", selectData);
});
```

---

**Solution: 2** [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/anzE3/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="alpha"">
    <option value="">Choose A-Z</option>
    <option value="0">0-9</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select id="store"">
    <option value="">Any Store</option>
    <option value="Arnotts">Arnotts</option>
    <option value="BrownThomas">BrownThomas</option>
    <option value="Dundrum">Dundrum</option>
</select>
<select id="category">
    <option value="">Any Category</option>
    <option value="Beauty">Beauty</option>
    <option value="Shoes">Shoes</option>
    <option value="Womens Wear">Womens Wear</option>
    <option value="Cosmetics">Cosmetics</option>
</select>

<div classs="brand-holder">
    <div class="brand-column">
        <h3>0-9</h3>
        <ul class="brand-list">
            <li data-alpha="0" data-store="Arnotts,BrownThomas" data-arnotts-category="Mens Wear, Cosmetics" data-dundrum-category="" data-brownthomas-category="Beauty" >1. Brand Name <i>[data-store="Arnotts,BrownThomas" data-arnotts-category="Mens Wear, Cosmetics" data-dundrum-category="" data-brownthomas-category="Beauty"]</i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="brand-column">
        <h3>A</h3>
        <ul class="brand-list">
            <li data-alpha="A" data-store="Arnotts,Dundrum,BrownThomas" data-arnotts-category="Womens Wear, Cosmetics" data-dundrum-category="Womens Wear" data-brownthomas-category="Beauty" >A Brand Name <i>[data-store="Arnotts,Dundrum,BrownThomas" data-arnotts-category="Womens Wear, Cosmetics" data-dundrum-category="Womens Wear" data-brownthomas-category="Beauty"]</i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function selectData() {
        var alpha = $("#alpha").val();
        var store = $("#store").val();
        var category = $("#category").val();
        var j;

        // Hide items
        $("li").each(function() {
            a = $(this).attr('data-alpha');
            s = $(this).attr('data-store').split(",");

            if (store == "") {
                c = ($(this).attr('data-arnotts-category') + "," + $(this).attr('data-dundrum-category') + "," + $(this).attr('data-brownThomas-category')).split(",");
            } else {
                c = $(this).attr('data-' + store.toLowerCase() + '-category');
            }

            // To be safe
            for(j = 0; j < s.length; j++) s[j] = s[j].trim();
            for(j = 0; j < c.length; j++) c[j] = c[j].trim();

            if((alpha == "" || a == alpha) && (store == "" || s.indexOf(store) != -1) && (category == "" | c.indexOf(category) != -1)) {
                $(this).removeClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }
        });

        // Hide empty sections
        $(".brand-list").each(function() {
            if($(this).children("li").not(".hidden").length > 0) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("hidden");
            } else {
                $(this).parent().addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
    }

    $("#alpha").on("change", selectData);
    $("#store").on("change", selectData);
    $("#category").on("change", selectData);
});
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for this answer, the only thing is, what if i want to the backend doesn't allow me segregate the categories relevant to the stores . here is an example  Chanel, Brown Thomas Sells women's wear, footwear,jewellery and accessories and beauty. Arnotts only sells beauty. 
Dundrum sells beauty and accessories. how would i achieve this?

Comment: also i have added edit to my question above, i have your above example working on this link. check it out http://www.d1257354-22503.cp.blacknight.com/brands/

Comment: at the moment, the data is attached to the li with data- field

Comment: i build this in the backend with advanced custom fields ACF http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ .

Comment: In the second HTML in your question, what is the relationship between `A Brand Name` and the `data` fields?

Comment: i dont really understand. i input images above, if they help

Comment: So, what should be your select box values? Is it just going to have 3 entries in 'stores'?

Comment: Yes there will only be those 3 values

Comment: OK, so what should happen when we choose an entry from `store` select? Also, when we select a `category` in category select, should it only show the items which match the selected `store`?

Comment: Example: What should happen `if store = "Arnotts" and category = "Beauty"`? Should the item `A Brand Name` show?

Comment: Updated answer with better solution: See **Solution 2**

Answer (score 1):

I would put the categories as CSS classes,
generate CSS rules for all categories,
and then change CSS class of the parent element.

Example:

```
<div id="list" class="container all">
    <div class="item startletterA storeFoo categoryNice">
</div>

<style>
    container     .item { display: none; }
    container.all .item { display: block; }
    container.startletterA item.startletterA { display: block; }
    container.startletterB item.startletterB { display: block; }
    ...
    container.storeFoo item.storeFoo { display: block; }
    container.storeBar item.storeBar { display: block; }
    ...
</style>

<select type="radio" onclick="$('list').replaceClass('startletter*', 'startletterA');"/>
```

The `replaceClass()` may not exist, but it's not hard to implement.

The advantage compared to JavaScript (jQuery) based solution is that this is a lot faster. Try it with thousands of items.

Answer (score 0):

Create a multidimensional JavaScript array, containing your 3 criteria as keys, so you can easily access the matching values and update the selects via jQuery.

i.e.

```
var myResults = new Array(
    'a' => new Array(
        'Arnotts' => new Array(
            'BrownThomas',
            'JohnDoe'
        )
    )
);
```

and later when values are selected:

```
var myResultsForSecondSelect = myResults[$('#select1').value()];
var myResultsForThirdSelect = myResults[$('#select1').value()][$('#select2').value()];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you do not want to load this stuff with AJAX, but have all the info available since the beginning. If so I would create a JSON object like so:

```
var data = {
    a: {
        storeA: ['categoryAA', 'categoryAB'],
        storeB: ['categoryBA', 'categoryBB']
    },
    b: {
    },
    c: {
    }
};
```

Then to fill in the selects you would create methods:

```
function updateOneLetter(data) {
    for(var key in data) {
        // fill in one letter select
    }
}

function udatesStores(data, oneLetter) {
    data = oneLetter ? [data[oneLetter]] : data;
    var keys = [];    
    $.each( data, function(i, n) {
        for(var key in n) {
            // fill in category
        }
    });
}

(...)
```

You would fill in categories similarly. You could create helper methods to simply retrieve filtered out values - instead of filling in select inline in the update functions above, and then work on the returned filtered out objects.